# Is there a way to determine the host OS and node version based on the node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Is there a more or less easy way to be able to tell (1) which OS (Windows or Linux), and (2) which version of nodejs `npm install` was run on by looking at the node_modules folder? I tried looking in `node_modules/.bin` but I see both bash and .cmd files.

*Quick back story for those interested: I maintain multiple applications, one of them being a legacy angular app we inherited. This app is extremely "fragile" and sensitive; last time we deployed it, it took the team a couple of days to get the environment "just right". We have multiple chroot environments and VMs, as well as user profiles with different nodejs setups, on both Linux and Windows, which are all fine-tuned for some of these legacy applications we manage.*

*The problem with this specific app is that I need to make a small change to it and recompile it, and the person managing it is not currently accessible. I am extremely worried about "disrupting" anything by touching the node_modules folder, since I know it took the team a long time and much trial & error to get everything just right (including package versions, a lot of which were tried and installed manually, etc). So after I make the change I need to ensure I'm calling everything from the same exact environment.*

Comment: In the context of an app so fragile it took _days_ to do what should just be a regular install in what's presumably a dev environment (because in prod you're usually just serving build outputs), why weren't the environment details recorded?

Comment: Its possible to determine using process object.

Comment: It seems you only have two choices.  1) Fully document from scratch how to build and configure this app for a specific environment so you can start from just the source and build and deploy it by following a specific procedure.  2) Punt on the the big problem and take an existing deployment and patch into it just your change so you don't have to re-invent the rest of the configuration.  Obviously, somebody needs to do #1 at some point so this isn't a continuing problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your reply. Yes, we know it should have been recorded; it was obviously a major process failure. We assumed we would have the app rewritten by now, but it is what it is. And you're correct -- we only save the build output in prod but I need the node environment to recompile it now (client wants a couple of css changes really) so I'm trying to recreate that same build environment without disrupting the "fragile" node-modules folder.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your reply. Please see my comment above for details but yes, we realize that #1 should have been done.

Answer (score -1):

Use [OS](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform) module

```
var os = require('os');
os.platform(); // 'darwin'
os.release(); //'10.8.0'
```

For node version,

```
console.log('Version: ' + process.version);
```

Comment: You can directly use `process.platform`  to determine the os

Comment: This tells you what platform is _currently_ being used, presumably the OP wants to know which one was _previously_ used.